# AES S-box calculation

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I am trying to design the s-box for AES. Quoting from Wikipedia, the algorithm for applying affine transformation in AES s-box calculation is

```
Let s (an 8-bit unsigned variable) be the input number.
Let result be 0.
For 5 times: 
   XOR result with s.
   Rotate s one bit to the left.
```

My question is why the multiplication is done this way? Why only 5 steps?

Comment: look at the affine matrix, each column and row only has 5 bits set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is first half of the calculation presented on the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Forward_S-box).

Notice that every bit of the result is actually a XOR of just five bits:

[image: affine matrix multiplication with result]

Now we slightly modify the algorithm you wrote to create five numbers by rotating the original number to the left and only then XOR them together:

[image: five numbers xored together give the same result as above]

As you can see the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for any S-box , I'll just compute the no. of set bits and do that much shifting and xor-ing?